# Android Studio java app - card value is printing, suit and rank are not

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm having trouble getting my blackjack game to display the hand that's being played. Very much at beginner level, currently doing a short course. It will only show the numeral of the card count, I presume because I've got suit and rank as integers? I would like to have the actual suit and rank be displayed as well. I'll post snippets of the code I think needs refactoring however I can post more if it can't be solved by those.

[card and deck class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZUVL.png)

[text view in main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrf1u.png)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use List of String instead of Integers and then place in the list following ranks: A, 2-10, J, Q, K. Using ArrayList you can always pick from following ranks by id of ArrayList insertion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have suit and rank as enums and listed as you said. I've tried changing the card class to be (Suit suit, Rank rank) {this.rank = rank; etc but if you see the picture of the deck above it doesn't like when it says (new Card());

Comment: To be honest... it's unclear what's the problem with your code. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry! Yes, basically I have the hand displaying on the UI as numbers only and I'm unsure of how to get it to display the suit and rank. I thought I could call my toString method but keep getting errors. I guess without posting all my code it's hard for you to see how to solve this...

Comment: Indeed, it is hard.